# Gson parse to POJO with custom key

Tags: java, json, gson

I have json data like this:

```
meds:
[
  {
     MedsID: 8063,
     updated_at: "2015-11-04T06:59:55",
     treatment_date: "2015-11-04T00:00:00",
     name: "name"
  }
],
scores: 
[
 {
   ScoreID: 75820,
   updated_at: "2015-11-04T06:59:55"
   dialysis_flow: 233,
 }
],
 dias: 
[
 {
   DiasID: 75820,
   updated_at: "2015-11-04T06:59:55"
   name: "K",
 }
]
```

And here is my Entities:

```
  public class BaseData{
      public long id;
  }

  public class Med extends BaseData{
      public String name;
      public String updated_at;
      public String treatment_date;
  }

  public class Score extends BaseData{
      public String updated_at;
      public int dialysis_flow;
  }

  public class Dias extends BaseData{
      public String name;
      public String updated_at;
      public String treatment_date;
  }
```

Because all entities are mapped from database with the `id` key (as I use orm db, it's loaded by property name ). So I need to parse all other keys `MedsID`, `DiasID`, `ScoreID` into `id` when mapping by gson. 
Is there any way to achieve that?

**Update**:
I use `registerTypeHierarchyAdapter` instead of `registerTypeAdapter` and it can work. But this way is **extremely slow** as my json data is very large.

```
public class DataDeserializer implements JsonDeserializer<BaseData>      {
@Override
public BaseData deserialize(JsonElement json, Type typeOfT, JsonDeserializationContext context) throws JsonParseException {
    JsonObject ja = json.getAsJsonObject();
    Gson gson = new Gson();
    final String[] mapIds = {"ScoreID", "MedsID", "DiasID"};
    BaseData data = gson.fromJson(ja, typeOfT);

    for (String idKey:mapIds){
        if(ja.has(idKey)){
            data.id = ja.get(idKey).getAsLong();
            break;
        }
    }

    return data;
    } 
}

 Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().registerTypeHierarchyAdapter( BaseData.class, new DataDeserializer() ).create();
```

Does anyone know other way to achieve that?

Comment: If your actual use case is so simple. I would just recreate the properties. If you don't like the `MedID` stuff and prefer `id`. You could use the `@SerializedName("MedID")` annotation on the properties. https://google.github.io/gson/apidocs/com/google/gson/annotations/SerializedName.html

Comment: I know that one. But this way is required to create each id for each entity. All my entities have to extend from BaseData which has `id` property. And I don't want to break all my entities structure (just let you know, I have 45 entity classes like above)

Comment: Write a custom deserializer. Fetch the name of the key in the key-value pair `MedsID: 8063` for instance and decide which instance to return. It'll behave like the factory pattern.

Comment: A custom deserializer will force you to create huge if/elseif/whatever blocks or dynamically instantiate classes (by finding a key ending with `ID` and then removing `ID` from that key name or something) imagine the work involved if you add a class or there is some object with another key ending with `ID`. I would just move the `id` property...

Comment: @AmazingDreams I did it and updated on my question. But this way is extremely slow.

Comment: You have to get rid of that loop. Furthermore you don't have to create a new Gson object each time; one should be contained in the `context` parameter. Perhaps you could also store the `mapIds` in a static member.

Answer (score 1):

The only way to achieve this is writing a custom de-serializer. Please see below example:

```
public class CustomDeserializer implements JsonDeserializer<Dias>{

    public Dias deserialize( JsonElement json, Type typeOfT, JsonDeserializationContext context ) throws JsonParseException{
        JsonObject ja = json.getAsJsonObject();

        Dias dias = new Gson().fromJson( ja, Dias.class );
        dias.id = ja.get( "DiasID" ).getAsLong();

        return dias;
    }

}
```

Register it;

```
 String dias = "{'DiasID':75820,'updated_at':'2015-11-04T06:59:55','name':'K'}";
 Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().registerTypeAdapter( Dias.class, new CustomDeserializer() ).create();
 Dias dias2 = gson.fromJson( dias, Dias.class );

 System.out.println( dias2.id );
```

Output:

```
75820
```

This is just an example, you can extend it by writing a deserializer for your own base class.

Comment: Your code can work. But when I use a custom deserializer and register for `BaseData`, the `deserialize` method isn't called. Look like it's required to register all sub classes.

Comment: Unfortunately there's no other way.

Comment: well, I updated my question. `registerTypeHierarchyAdapter` can help. But it's extremely slow