# Create model from JSON array of object. Android

Tags: android

What I'm trying to do is save surveys, however these surveys can be search by two different methods, one where the surveys is sent out to a group of people and where the survey is sent out to the individual.

These is the full json response

```
{
  "group": [
    {
      "id": 2,
      "evaluation_id": 1,
      "user_id": null,
      "group_id": 1,
      "created_at": "2020-04-20 11:04:31",
      "updated_at": "2020-04-20 11:04:31",
      "evaluation": {
        "id": 1,
        "survey_id": 1,
        "init_date": "2020-04-13 12:00:00",
        "end_date": "2020-04-30 12:00:00",
        "report": 0,
        "report_date": null,
        "report_end": null,
        "created_at": "2020-04-20 11:04:21",
        "updated_at": "2020-04-20 11:04:21",
        "survey": {
          "id": 1,
          "name": "asdfasdfds group",
          "description": "<p>adfadsfa<strong><em>dsf<\/em><\/strong>asdfadsf asd asdf f sad fsd<\/p>",
          "user_id": 1,
          "anonymous": 0,
          "created_at": "2020-04-20 11:04:21",
          "updated_at": "2020-04-20 11:04:31"
        }
      }
    }
  ],
  "single": [
    {
      "id": 5,
      "evaluation_id": 2,
      "user_id": 1,
      "group_id": null,
      "created_at": "2020-04-21 11:00:19",
      "updated_at": "2020-04-21 11:00:19",
      "evaluation": {
        "id": 2,
        "survey_id": 2,
        "init_date": "2020-04-13 12:00:00",
        "end_date": "2020-04-24 12:00:00",
        "report": 0,
        "report_date": null,
        "report_end": null,
        "created_at": "2020-04-20 11:05:43",
        "updated_at": "2020-04-20 11:05:43",
        "survey": {
          "id": 2,
          "name": "asdfa single",
          "description": "<p>asdfa<\/p>",
          "user_id": 1,
          "anonymous": 1,
          "created_at": "2020-04-20 11:05:43",
          "updated_at": "2020-04-21 11:00:19"
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

What I'm interested in saving is the object inside group and single, not all of it. How can I take this and create the model where this is saved in, since this is an object in an object in an object. I would mainly like to save the `evaluation` and `survey` object in my model.

The model currently looks like this, however I know this probably won't work.

```
public class SurveyItem {
    private int mSurveyIcon;
    private String mSurveyTitle, mSurveyDesc, mSurveyStartDate, mSurveyEndDate;

    public SurveyItem(int surveyIcon, String title, String desc, String sDate, String eDate) {
        mSurveyIcon = surveyIcon;
        mSurveyTitle = title;
        mSurveyDesc = desc;
        mSurveyStartDate = sDate;
        mSurveyEndDate = eDate;
    }

    public int getmSurveyIcon() {
        return mSurveyIcon;
    }

    public String getmSurveyTitle() {
        return mSurveyTitle;
    }

    public String getmSurveyDesc() {
        return mSurveyDesc;
    }

    public String getmSurveyStartDate() {
        return mSurveyStartDate;
    }

    public String getmSurveyEndDate() {
        return mSurveyEndDate;
    }
}
```

Since there are Json objects, how can I correct this model?

Comment: Your question is not clear. Are you using any library like Gson for searlisation?

Comment: I'm going to make a Retrofit @GET to get this info and then I would do a foreach to set them in a RecyclerView, that's why I need this model class. I do add a GsonBuilder to my Retrofit client. 
```
Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().serializeNulls().setLenient().create();
```

Comment: From what I understand you have some custom logic to to deserialzie your json. Since you are using gson you can provide a custom deserliazer to Json. Take a look at this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33760396/gson-parse-to-pojo-with-custom-key

Comment: @SaranSankaran if by Seralisation you mean in the model add `@SerializedName("name")` I don't do that I would rather just use the real name

Answer (score -1):

Do use this website to convert JSON into the model:
http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/

You can select the source type JSON and annotation type whatever you are using like GSON as the converter. It will convert your JSON into model class